# personal facebook feed to website using javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have got a problem I want to have an open facebook feed published on my website but is this possible without logging on to facebook, with just using the accesstoken I have got for the Graph API. I am using javascript and I only see options where the user has to log in to see his own feed. In short is there a way to set the accesstoken instead of logging in.

```
FB.init({
    appId      : '165058340734275',
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.10'
});
FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
//GET graph.facebook.com
console.log('test');
FB.api(
    '/me',
    access_token: "ACCESS_TOKEN",
    'GET',
    {"fields":"id,name,feed{attachments,message,story,created_time,likes}"},
    function(response) {
      // Insert your code here
      console.log(response);
    }
  );
```

Comment: Sure you could specify an access token ... but not as long as you are operating in client-side JavaScript; you should never expose access tokens that don’t belong to the current app user in client-side code.

Comment: But is it in another way possible to display the facebook feed on my website by using Graph api (without logging in).

Comment: Are we talking about the feed of a user profile or a page here? For a user profile, you would need to request permission from them to be able to read their posts first; for a page you can use your app or a page access token (but again, only server-side.)